# Array bidimensional String, acceso a datos

Tags: java, string, array-bidimensional

Tengo un `Array bidimensional` con asignaturas y notas (TODO `String`), y quiero mostrar las asignaturas con valores iguales o superiores a 9, lo he hecho "a lo bruto" pero tengo a sensación de que estoy haciendo "trampa", muestro el código a continuación:

```
import java.io.*;
public class consulta {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada); 

        String [][] bi ={
            {" M01","8","5","10"},
            {" M02","3","8","7"},
            {" M03","9","7","6"},
            {" M04","10","4","9"}
        };

        System.out.println("\nLos elementos del Array son:");
        for (int fila=0; fila<bi.length; fila++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int columna=0; columna<bi.length; columna++){
                System.out.print(bi[fila][columna]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.print("_______________________");
        System.out.print("\n ELIJA UNA OPCIÓN:\n");

        int op;

        /*repetirá el menú con los mismos números introducidos*/
        do {                
            System.out.println("0.- salir");        
            System.out.println("1.- Muestra Todas las Asignaturas");
            System.out.println("2.- Puntuación de una Asignatura");
            System.out.println("3.- Asignaturas con puntuacion >=9:");
            System.out.println("4.- Puntuacion más baja");
            System.out.println("Opcion: ");
            op = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


            switch (op){
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:     
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Las Asignaturas son: "+bi [0][0]+" "+bi [2][0]+" "+bi [3][0]+"\n");
                    System.out.print("_______________________");
                    System.out.print("\n ELIJA UNA OPCIÓN:\n"); 

                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }while (op!=0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias incluir todo el codigo ?? dices utilizar un switch, pero que evaluas en el??

Comment: Si, es hacer "trampa". Deberías de iterar en el `array bidimensional` y quedarte con los valores que cumplan esa condición `>=9` podrias guardar estos valores en otro `array/arraylist`.

Answer (score 1):

Ya estas iterando en el `array`, por lo que solo tendrías que añadir la condición y crearte un string que es el que luego pintaras concatenandolo:

En la condición deberías de tener en cuenta:

- que no sea la primera columna ya que la primera columna es la
  asignatura.
- Y que la columna sea >= 9
- Y que la asignatura no este ya en el `String` (para evitar duplicados)

```
(columna > 0 
    && Integer.parseInt(bi[fila][columna]) >= 9 
    && !asignaturasMatriculaHonor.contains(bi[fila][0]))
```

Ojo con esta última condición si una asignatura se llama `M01` y otra se llama `M012`
si tienes añadida la `M012` en el `String` y se busca el `contains` de `M01` te dirá que ya existe y no se añadirá. En tu ejemplo no llega a ocurrir, pero para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Podrías usar una expresión regular para está última condición

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(bi[fila][0].trim()+"\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(asignaturasMatriculaHonor);
(columna > 0 
        && Integer.parseInt(bi[fila][columna]) >= 9 
        && !m.find())
```

Código:

```
String asignaturasMatriculaHonor = "";
for (int fila=0; fila<bi.length; fila++){
    System.out.println();
    for(int columna=0; columna<bi.length; columna++){
        if(columna > 0 && Integer.parseInt(bi[fila][columna]) >= 9 && !asignaturasMatriculaHonor.contains(bi[fila][0])){
            asignaturasMatriculaHonor += bi[fila][0] +" ";
        }
        System.out.print(bi[fila][columna]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

System.out.print("Las Asignaturas son: "+asignaturasMatriculaHonor +"\n");
```